# Концепция ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Немного туманная для меня эта концепция.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при разработке собственных контролов нужно отдавать предпочтение `ControlTemplate` с каким-то дефолтным стилем, чтобы в дальнейшем его могли переопределить, или в каких-то отдельных случаях `UserControl` может иметь смысл?

И правильно ли я понимаю, что при подходе через `ControlTemplate` конечный пользователь может превратить контрол во что ему хочется?

Comment: `ControlTemplate` следует использовать если вам нужно просто переопределить шаблон какого-то контрола, например кнопки, но если вам понадобится сделать какой-то кастомный контрол (например при нажатии на кнопку выполнять какие-то действия в соседнем элементе) для этого используется `UserControl`, где вы можете задать логику для своего контрола